# 404 error on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, httpresponse

I am trying to add Facebook like/share to http://labs.jstor.org/shakespeare/macbeth. I’ve tried several different ways of adding it, including the HTML5 and XFBML options from developers.facebook.com and from AddThis.

I made sure to include the og: title, type, url, and image meta tags as shown:

The open graph debugger tool at developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ returns a 404. I checked in Firebug to make sure there wasn't a 404 header coming across. When clicked, the like/share buttons show the page as "Page Not Found"

What is going on here?

Comment: <meta property="og:title" content="Shakespeare Browser" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://labs.jstor.org/shakespeare/macbeth" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://labs.jstor.org/static/default/images/ShakespeareBrowser_SubHeader_250_02.jpeg" />

Comment: your URLs there don't look correct, you're missing the protocol identifier for one (e.g. `http://`) - have you checked the calls Facebook's crawler is making to your server and verified that you're not returning a 404? it uses a different user agent header than your own browser so you may have code which returns different content to different browsers here

Comment: Ok, set to:
<meta property="og:title" content="Shakespeare Browser" /><meta property="og:type" content="website" /><meta property="og:url" content="http://labs.jstor.or/shakespeare/" /><meta property="og:image" content="http://labs.jstor.org/static/default/images/ShakespeareBrowser_SubHeader_250_02.jpeg" />

I took the http:// out just in this post, because I wasn't allowed to use that many links, then I ended up pasted them into a comment instead and forgot to put it back the way it actually was in my code. 
You mean check server logs for that?

Comment: @Igy Ahh, went to a server header checker tool and sure enough, any bot agents (including Facebook's) are returned a 404. Will modify server and network settings to fix that. Thanks so much! I'd accept your answer if it was an answer instead of a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your server code and make sure you're returning the correct meta tags to Facebook - if you have special user agent handling, you might be returning the correct tags to regular browsers but the wrong tags to Facebook, which can make debugging more difficult

Comment: There was server-side special user agent handling through Fastly that I wasn't aware of. That was the problem, thanks!